# Tell firefox to use client certificate for specific site

Tags: firefox, https, ssl-certificate

I am looking for a good way to restrict access to my staging environment without resorting to an ip based firewall.
Basically its a replica of the public production site, that I only want certain people to be able to access. I tried getting this done with http basic auth, but unfortunately, getting this to work with with the api and file subdomain is pretty tedious.

So I was thinking of using https client certificates (which I can send to authorized users) to authenticate and authorize the users on the staging environment. I have created such a client certificate using openssl and I also know how to verify client certificates on nginx. Now I need to be able to tell firefox to only use a specific client certificate on a certain site. But so far I have not been able to figure out how to make firefox use my client certificate on any site.

So basically, how can I make firefox use my client certficate for my stagning environment?

Comment: The webserver decides which certificates are acceptable and tells this the browser in the TLS handshake which then checks the available client certificates and asks the user to select one.

Comment: seems to work now, thanks a lot